# Что сделать чтоб цена была сверху?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.categorie {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.price {
  padding-left: 250px;
}

.product:first-child {
  padding-top: 150px;
}

.product {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=1">Жесткий диск</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=2">Жесткий диск</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=3">Жесткий диск</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=4">xbox 360</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=5">xbox 360</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=6">xbox 360</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=2">Игровые приставки</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=7">Gtx 1050 ti</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="title"><a href="product.php?id=8">ФЫЫФЫ</a></div>
    <div class="categorie"><a href="index.php?cat=1">Компьютеры</a></div>
    <div class="price">1000</div>
  </div>2<a href="index.php?page=1">1 </a><a href="index.php?page=2">2 </a></div>
```

Comment: Загрузите сюда html, который у вас на выходе.

Comment: @IliaBrykin Загрузил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил `div` и чуть-чуть стилей:

```css
.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.price {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.product img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div>
      <div class="title"><a href="">Жесткий диск</a></div>
      <div class="categorie"><a href="">Компьютеры</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div>
      <div class="title"><a href="">Жесткий диск</a></div>
      <div class="categorie"><a href="">Компьютеры</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div>
      <div class="title"><a href="">Жесткий диск</a></div>
      <div class="categorie"><a href="">Компьютеры</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div>
      <div class="title"><a href="">Жесткий диск</a></div>
      <div class="categorie"><a href="">Компьютеры</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
    <div>
      <div class="title"><a href="">Жесткий диск</a></div>
      <div class="categorie"><a href="">Компьютеры</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price">Договорная</div>
  </div>
```